# How to avoid `command not found` error when re-sourcing bash configuration with a key binding?

Tags: bash, configuration

I'm using `bash` version `4.3.48`:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I'm trying to define a key binding, using the key sequence `C-x r`, to reload the configuration of `bash + readline`. [Thanks to @Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370427/232487), I included this code in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind    '"\e[99i~": re-read-init-file'
bind -x '"\e[99b~": . ~/.bashrc'
bind    '"\C-xr":   "\e[99i~\e[99b~"'
```

It works, except that `bash` writes an error message when I hit `C-x r`, which I don't understand:

```
\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf: command not found
```

I thought that maybe it was due to an interaction with some other settings that I changed, so I deleted everything in `~/.bashrc`, except for the 3 lines defining the key binding `C-x r`.

But there's still an error message:

```
: command not found
```

So, I tried a simpler `bashrc` with only one key binding:

```
bind -x '"\C-xr": . ~/.bashrc'
```

This time, hitting `C-x r` produces the error:

```
\udccf
      : command not found
```

However, if I comment the line `bind -x '"\C-xr": . ~/.bashrc'` in my `bashrc` file, and I execute the command in an interactive `bash` shell, then everything works fine. No error message, and the configuration is properly re-sourced.

So, I guess I should write a guard around this key binding to prevent `bash` from re-defining it, if it has already been done. But I don't know how to test the existence of a key binding. Besides, I would like to better understand what happens with these errors.

---

I don't know if it matters, but I never start `bash` directly, I always start if from `zsh`. When I want to test some command that I'm going to write in a bash script, I open a terminal (using `zsh` as the default shell), then I execute `bash` from there. So, maybe `bash` inherits some environment variable from `zsh` which causes the first error message?

Also, as it was asked in the comment section, here's the output of `hexdump -C ~/.bashrc` with only the 3 key bindings:

```
00000000  62 69 6e 64 20 20 20 20  27 22 5c 65 5b 39 39 69  |bind    '"\e[99i|
00000010  7e 22 3a 20 72 65 2d 72  65 61 64 2d 69 6e 69 74  |~": re-read-init|
00000020  2d 66 69 6c 65 27 0a 62  69 6e 64 20 2d 78 20 27  |-file'.bind -x '|
00000030  22 5c 65 5b 39 39 62 7e  22 3a 20 2e 20 7e 2f 2e  |"\e[99b~": . ~/.|
00000040  62 61 73 68 72 63 27 0a  62 69 6e 64 20 20 20 20  |bashrc'.bind    |
00000050  27 22 5c 43 2d 78 72 22  3a 20 20 20 22 5c 65 5b  |'"\C-xr":   "\e[|
00000060  39 39 69 7e 5c 65 5b 39  39 62 7e 22 27 0a        |99i~\e[99b~"'.|
0000006e
```

Here's the hex dump with a `bashrc` containing only `bind -x '"\C-xr": . ~/.bashrc'`:

```
00000000  62 69 6e 64 20 2d 78 20  27 22 5c 43 2d 78 72 22  |bind -x '"\C-xr"|
00000010  3a 20 2e 20 7e 2f 2e 62  61 73 68 72 63 27 0a     |: . ~/.bashrc'.|
0000001f
```

And here's my full `bashrc`:

```
case "$-" in
  *i*) ;;
  *) return ;;
esac
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
  debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "
alias cdr='cd "$(ls -dt */ | head -1)"'
export HISTCONTROL="ignoreboth:erasedups"
export HISTIGNORE="clear:history:"
export HISTFILE="${HOME}/.bash_eternal_history"
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; ${PROMPT_COMMAND}"
cd() {
  if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    builtin cd "${PWD/$1/$2}"
  elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    builtin cd "$1"
  else
    builtin cd
  fi
}
shopt -s autocd
shopt -s checkwinsize
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s histappend
shopt -s histreedit
shopt -s histverify
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
. ~/.fzf.bash
. ~/.shrc
bind '" ": magic-space'
bind '"\C-xc": "\C-a\C-kvimdiff <() <()\C-b\C-b\C-b\C-b\C-b"'
bind '"\C-xf":  character-search'
bind '"\C-xF":  character-search-backward'
bind    '"\e[99i~": re-read-init-file'
bind -x '"\e[99b~": . ~/.bashrc'
bind    '"\C-xr":   "\e[99i~\e[99b~"'
bind '"\C-x\C-s": "sudo !!\C-m\C-m"'
bind -x '"\C-x\C-t": fzf-file-widget'
bind '"\C-t": transpose-chars'
bind '"\C-x\C-v": "\C-e | vim -R -\C-m"'
bind '"\em": "\C-aman \ef\C-k\C-m"'
bind '"\e\C-b":  "\C-e >/dev/null 2>&1 &\C-m"'
```

---

Edit:

I've tried to wrap the command `. ~/.bashrc` inside a function, and call the latter in the key binding. Using the following syntax:

```
bind    '"\e[99i~": re-read-init-file'
bind -x '"\e[99b~": MyFunc'
bind    '"\C-xr":   "\e[99i~\e[99b~"'
MyFunc () {
  . ~/.bashrc
}
```

And I've discovered that the error was influenced by the length of the name of the function. Here's a table, where the left column contains different names for the function, and where the right column contains the error messages (if any):

```
┌───────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ a                 │ \udc99: command not found                                                                   │
│ ab                │ \udc92: command not found                                                                   │
│ abc               │ : command not found                                                                         │
│ abcd              │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found │
│ abcde             │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found       │
│ abcdef            │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found             │
│ abcdefg           │ no error                                                                                    │
│ abcdefgh          │ : command not found                                                                         │
│ abcdefghi         │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                               │
│ abcdefghij        │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                     │
│ abcdefghijk       │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                           │
│ abcdefghijkl      │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                                 │
│ abcdefghijklm     │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                                       │
│ abcdefghijklmn    │ \udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                                             │
│ abcdefghijklmno   │ \udcdf: command not found                                                                   │
│ abcdefghijklmnop  │ : command not found                                                                         │
│ abcdefghijklmnopq │ no error                                                                                    │
└───────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I also tried a different function where I reconnect the input of the `. ~/.bashrc` command to the terminal (inspiration from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370475/how-to-test-if-the-current-zsh-shell-has-already-executed-dircolors-and-stty#comment658718_370475)):

```
bind    '"\e[99i~": re-read-init-file'
bind -x '"\e[99b~": MyFunc'
bind    '"\C-xr":   "\e[99i~\e[99b~"'
MyFunc () {
  . ~/.bashrc </dev/tty
}
```

Here are the results:

```
┌──────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ a                    │ 9}: command not found                                                                                                │
│ ab                   │ \udcdd: command not found                                                                                            │
│ abc                  │ : command not found                                                                                                  │
│ abcd                 │ no error                                                                                                             │
│ abcde                │ no error                                                                                                             │
│ abcdef               │ no error                                                                                                             │
│ abcdefg              │ no error                                                                                                             │
│ abcdefgh             │ : command not found                                                                                                  │
│ abcdefghi            │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                                        │
│ abcdefghij           │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                                              │
│ abcdefghijk          │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                                                    │
│ abcdefghijkl         │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                                                          │
│ abcdefghijklm        │ \udcdf\udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                                                                │
│ abcdefghijklmn       │ \udcdf\udcdf: command not found                                                                                      │
│ abcdefghijklmno      │ \udcdf: command not found                                                                                            │
│ abcdefghijklmnop     │ : command not found                                                                                                  │
│ abcdefghijklmnopq    │ no error                                                                                                             │
│ abcdefghijklmnopqr   │ no error                                                                                                             │
│ abcdefghijklmnopqrs  │ no error                                                                                                             │
│ abcdefghijklmnopqrst │ \udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf\udccf$: command not found │
└──────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Can you add `head -n 2 .bashrc | hexdump -C`?

Comment: Note that octal 317 is hex CF and U+DCCF is in the low surrogate range (invalid in UTF-8, never appears alone). It seems like there's something odd, possibly invisible, within the file.

Comment: Ok, more usefully, can you give a hexdump of the relevant lines from the file, wherever they are? You can just copy out from the middle when they start. If anything else unprintable appears include that too - the only thing should be 0a (LF).

Comment: @MichaelHomer I removed all the comments and empty lines in my `bashrc`, and re-executed the `hexdump` command. I also included my whole `bashrc`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I'm sorry, I didn't fully understand your request the first time. But I think I have now. I've included the hex dump of only the key binding lines. I also removed the question relative to `zsh`, as it is probably a different issue. I'll write another question for it. Again, thank you for your help.