# How to test if the current zsh shell has already executed `dircolors` and `stty` commands?

Tags: zsh, configuration

I'm using `zsh` version 5.3.1:

```
% zsh --version
zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I'm trying to define a key binding, using the key sequence `C-x r`, to reload the configuration of `zsh`. Thanks to [@Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370427/232487), I included this code in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
reread_zshrc () {
. ~/.zshrc
}
zle -N reread_zshrc
bindkey '^Xr' reread_zshrc
```

It works, except that when I hit `C-x r`, `zsh` complains with the errors:

```
stty: 'standard input': Bad file descriptor
stty: 'standard input': Bad file descriptor
dircolors: /home/user/.dircolors: Bad file descriptor
```

I can reproduce these errors with the following minimal `zshrc`:

```
stty -ixon
stty quit undef
eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)"

reread_zshrc () {
. ~/.zshrc
}

zle -N reread_zshrc
bindkey '^Xr' reread_zshrc
```

---

Here are the reasons why I included the 2 `stty` commands, and the `dircolors` command in my `zshrc`.

`stty -ixon` prevents the terminal driver from interpreting `C-s` and `C-q` as terminal flow controls: by default, `C-s` freezes the terminal and `C-q` unfreeze it. It allows to use `C-s` and `C-q` in key bindings for the shell or the text editor, without freezing the terminal.

`stty quit undef` prevents the terminal driver from sending the `SIGQUIT` signal when `C-\` is pressed. Again, it allows to use this key in a key binding without the foreground process to quit.

`eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)"` asks the `ls` command to read its configuration from `~/.dircolors`. It allows to customize the colors from the output of a `ls` command.

I suppose I need to protect these 3 lines from being re-sourced by `zsh` if they've already been executed in the current shell. But I don't know which condition to write:

```
if <stty and dircolors haven't been executed already>; then
  stty -ixon
  stty quit undef
  eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)"
if
```

Besides, I would like to better understand these error messages, because if I execute them in an interactive `zsh` shell, they don't cause any issue. Why do they only raise errors from this key binding.

Comment: Try changing `. ~/.zshrc` to `. ~/.zshrc < /dev/tty`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you very much. It seems to work perfectly. I don't have any error messages, and the configuration is properly re-sourced. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe `$(echoti xon)` can be used to check the status of `stty ixon`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `zle` widgets, it seems `zsh` closes stdin. I suppose `zsh` wants to avoid commands in those widgets interfering directly with user input, but it would be more sensible to redirect stdin from /dev/null instead ([that will be fixed in the next release](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/4d007e269d1892e45e44ff92b6b9a1a205ff64d5)).

When stdin (file descriptor 0) is closed, that means the first file a command opens becomes its stdin (as file descriptors are allocated from the first free one).

In `dircolors`, that triggers a bug. `dircolors` opens your `~/.dircolors`, and then tries to make it its stdin without noticing it was already its stdin (because that's the fd `open()` returns). So, the `dup2(0,0)` (dup stdin onto itself) fails with a EBADF error which `dircolors` reports.

`stty` sets the settings of the terminal open on its stdin. Here, stdin is closed, so `stty` returns with an error.

Here, you can change your widget so it restores stdin to the terminal:

```
reread_zshrc () . ~/.zshrc < $TTY
```

But note that changing the tty settings from within a `zle` widget (though I don't know what your `stty` command does) is a bad idea as `zle` sets the tty in a special mode for line editing which you don't want to mess up with (and at the end of editing, the normal tty settings will be restored anyway, so the changes you're making will be lost).

So maybe instead you should make stdin `/dev/null` (as you don't really want to be doing things with the terminal there), but `stty` would still complain (as `/dev/null` is not a tty device), so you may also want to redirect stderr to /dev/null to hide those error messages (though it would hide *all* error messages):

```
reread_zshrc() . ~/.zshrc < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```